# replace function in JS controller Lightning

Tags: lightning, javascript

I want to replace the call back response with the component value.

```
var actionAcc = component.get("c.getPickupLineItems");
  //  alert("pickup response: " +actionAcc);
    actionAcc.setParams({
        "recordID": OrderRecordId
    });
    actionAcc.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
       // alert("State: " +state);

        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            var JsonString = JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue());

            var JsonParsed = JSON.parse(JsonString);
            var ItemsPickArray = component.get("v.MaterialPickupObj");  //Taking the current value
            alert("ItemsPickUpArray: " +ItemsPickArray);
            var ItemsPickArray1 = ItemsPickArray.replace(ItemsPickArray, response.getReturnValue());  //replacing the value with new value

            component.set("v.MaterialPickupObj",ItemsPickArray1);

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(actionAcc);
```

But this is not working. Getting error like below-
[image]

I also tried with -

```
var ItemsPickArray1 = ItemsPickArray.join(ItemsPickArray, response.getReturnValue());
```

The previous error is not coming but not getting value in my application.
Please help me.

Comment: Whats the type of attribute MaterialPickupObj?

Comment: This is an array type of Custom Object, like 
<aura:attribute name="MaterialPickupObj" type="Pickup_Order__c[]"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only line of code you actually need is:

```
component.set("v.MaterialPickupObj", response.getReturnValue());
```

There's normally no need to stringify/parse/etc like you're attempting here, assuming you're already returning a list of records from your Apex code.